# pandas `read_csv` does not read empty Multiindex file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, multi-index

What I would like to do (but doesn't work):

`test.csv`:

```
,info,info,info,name,name,name
,date,amount,mark,Charlie,Skyler,Alex
```

`program.py`:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0, header=[0,1])  # -> IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, if there is only one line in the header, it seems to work, i.e.:

`test.csv`:

```
,date,amount,mark,Charlie,Skyler,Alex
```

`program.py`:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)  # -> returns an empty data frame with the correct header
```

The same thing works also when there is at least one entry, i.e.:

`test.csv`:

```
,info,info,info,name,name,name
,date,amount,mark,Charlie,Skyler,Alex
0,1/1/2022,100,A,3,4,1
```

`program.py`:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0, header=[0,1]) # -> returns a multi-index data frame
```

To be honest, I don't really understand what's the difference between the first case and the second case is, but especially why the latter two cases work but not the first one.

Comment: When I run your code, I don't get an error, I get an empty df with a multiindex in the columns: `[(info, date), (info, amount), (info, mark), (name, Charlie), (name, Skyler), (name, Alex)]`

Comment: Aha! Indeed I just gave it a try in the python 3.8 environment and it worked. I was using python 3.7 when I was testing this. I keep this issue open because it might help other people, but thank you for your info!